# How can i fix this stack overflow error?

Tags: java

```
    public Dog[] dogList =
    {
        new Dog(1, 2, "Bacon"),
        new Dog(3, 4, "Cheese"),
        new Dog(8, 6, "Steak"),
        new Dog(5, 6, "Lamb"),
        new Dog(12, 14, "Caviar")
    };
```

whenever i run my program i have a StackOverflowError.

```
    System.out.println(new Dog(2, 3, "hi").compareTo(new Dog(1, 2, "a")));
```

I run it via  that code.
Dog class source code:

```
package Luka;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Dog extends Animal implements Comparable<Dog>{



    public void eat(String food)
    {
        System.out.println("The dog enjoyed his meal of " + food);
    }
    public int compareTo(Dog other)
    {   
        if(this.age < other.age)
        {
            int returnNum = -1;
            return returnNum;
        }
        else if(this.age > other.age)
        {
            int returnNum = 1;
            return returnNum;
        }
        else
        {
            int returnNum = 0;
            return returnNum;
        }
    }
    public String toString(int weight,int age,String foodType)
    {
        return "The dog weighs "+weight+", is "+age+" years old, and eats "+foodType+" for dinner.";
    }
    public Dog(int weight, int age, String foodType)
    {
        this.weight = weight;
        this.age = age;
        this.foodType = foodType;
    }
        public Dog[] dogList =
        {
            new Dog(1, 2, "Bacon"),
            new Dog(3, 4, "Cheese"),
            new Dog(8, 6, "Steak"),
            new Dog(5, 6, "Lamb"),
            new Dog(12, 14, "Caviar")
        };
}
```

Comment: Please provide the `Dog` class' source code too.

Comment: That exception isn't explained by the code you posted so far. Most likely, your constructor or your compareTo() call does some recursion (which it shouldnt do).

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a variable initializer, the code to initialize the variable is effectively prepended to your constructor(s).

For example:

```
public Dog[] dogList = { new Dog(1, 2, "Bacon"), ... };

public Dog(int weight, int age, String foodType) {
  this.weight = weight;
  this.age = age;
  this.foodType = foodType;
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
public Dog[] dogList;

public Dog(int weight, int age, String foodType) {
  this.dogList = { new Dog(1, 2, "Bacon"), ... };

  this.weight = weight;
  this.age = age;
  this.foodType = foodType;
}
```

so you're unconditionally invoking the `Dog` constructor inside the `Dog` constructor.

Remove the `dogList` from the `Dog` class, or make it `static`.